# Integration of Dirichlet

Tags: calculus, integration

If someone can explain to me -

Consider $F(x) = x$ , $D(x) = $  Dirichlet  function

1. Why $H(x) = F(x)D(x)$ is not integrable by Reimann.
2. and why the-the Set of uncontinuous points in Dirichlet isn't a null set?

Comment: To clarify:  by the Dirichlet function you mean the function which is $1$ on the rationals and $0$ otherwise?  That function is nowhere continuous.

Comment: Exactly what  i mean , but why $H(x)$ is not integrable?

Comment: Because you can (easily) construct partitions on which the approximation to the integral would be $0$, and others on which the approximations would converge to $\int x dx$.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) for an explanation as to why the Dirichlet function itself is not Riemann integrable.